# Inserting a file at a particular point in a Word document using Python

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I've got an HTML table that I'm trying to insert into a Word document. This code inserts the table at the start of the document and it looks great except for the location. I need to be able to specify a location mid-document for the table to land. I could alter the document to include some kind of marker if there's a way to get the code to use the marker as an insertion point for the table. Thanks

```
import win32com.client
def InsertTable(LetterPath, TablePath):
    app = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
    app.Visible = 0
    app.DisplayAlerts = 0
    app.Documents.Open(LetterPath)
    app.Selection.InsertFile(TablePath)
    app.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges=True)
    app.Quit()
```

Comment: You are inserting at the selection point (`app.Selection.InsertFile(TablePath)`) which seems to be at the beginning of the document by default.  So you need to figure out a way of changing the selection or do `InsertFile` on a different object.

Comment: It would seem to me you could move the selection using [`Selection.GoTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821348.aspx).  You can specify the kind of thing you want to go to by using the [`WdGoToItem` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdgotoitem%28v=office.11%29.aspx).  Let me know how this goes as I am just guessing based on Google searches.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion makes sense but I'm having trouble trying out. The only examples I saw on the Selection.GoTo page on Microsoft seem to be using it in VB. I'm having syntax trouble trying to make it work in Python. I'm very much a beginner. Here are the variations I've tried. The first is the example on MS's site:---app.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToField, Name:="TableField"
    ---app.Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToField, Name:="TableField")
    ---app.Selection.GoTo(What="wdGoToField", Name="TableField")
    ---app.Selection.GoTo("wdGoToField", "TableField")

Comment: Ended up adding this line before "InsertFile" line so that the selection location gets changed to wherever I put "TableMarker" inside the document... app.Selection.Find.Execute("TableMarker", False, False, False, False, False, True, 0, False, "", 1)